# SDL does not give me keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, sdl, polling

I am trying to use SDL to poll keyboard states for a simulator I am writing. I am using the following code to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // SDL setup
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVENTS) != 0) {
        cerr << "SDL Initialization failure." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    atexit(SDL_Quit);

    const Uint8* keyboard = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

    while (1) {
        SDL_PumpEvents();
        if (keyboard[SDL_SCANCODE_UP])
            cerr << "KEY UP" << endl;
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program starts without problems, but despite pressing the up arrow key, I never get the KEY UP output. I have the sneaky suspicion I am missing something, but can't figure out what.

Comment: You need to create a window and SDL will give you events for that window, passed by window manager. When window is not active you'll not receive events as they're not yours (you may still get e.g. mouse move, but not kbd). Grabbing global keyboard events is quite different task and I don't think SDL covers that, or ever will.

Comment: Hmm, was rather hoping it could grab the keyboard events from the commandline it is running in, but if that isn't the case I'll take a different approach

Comment: No, if you need keyboard presses from terminal then you need to read `stdin` or use something else, like ncurses.